# PG::GroupingError not used in aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, grouping, aggregate-functions

I am seeing this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "playlistships.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
2014-11-10T01:25:00.821301+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

when I run this query:

```
Playlistship.select("playlist_id, max(updated_at)").order('updated_at desc').group(:playlist_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
```

It seems I am using `updated_at` in an aggregate function, so I'm not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: If I got the question correctly, you're trying to run something similar to:

```
SELECT playlist_id, max(updated_at)
FROM PlayListChip
GROUP BY playlist_id
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

**Reason**: The error is because you're trying to ORDER BY a column (updated_at) and not the 'aggregated' updated_at ... If you think about it, this wouldn't work. This is because the *ORDER BY* needs to be the same aggregation as the SELECT field (or it needs to be one of the GROUP BY fields).

**Solution**: You may want to replace

```
Playlistship.select("playlist_id, max(updated_at)").order('updated_at desc').group(:playlist_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
```

with

```
Playlistship.select("playlist_id, max(updated_at)").order('max(updated_at) desc').group(:playlist_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
```